# quick question about a directory tarring script

Tags: unix, scripting, tar

Hey, 
I need to tar all the directories in a certain directory. I have two issues, I keep getting the hidden directories, which I don't want, and I need them to be placed somewhere else once they are tarred.

Here is what I am doing now:

```
for file in $(find /data/shares/builds/place1/ -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -regex '.*' \) );do tar zcf  ../Place2_$1_$timeStamp/$file.tar.gz $file;done
```

I am still getting the hidden files, and I am getting an error that the first location does not exist. I am getting the message:

../Place2_1.0.1_1012031412//data/shares/builds/Place1/Project1.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory

Anyone see anything I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your find command isn't proper (try testing it by itself).

This find command should give you the list of directories you want:

```
find /data/shares/builds/place1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name '.*'
```

(you need -mindepth 1 to avoid listing the containing directory itself, and the ! -name works as you intend whereas your regex method doesn't).

Second, notice that the output of find includes the full pathnames of each directory (e.g. "/data/shares/builds/place1/Project1" so **that whole string gets assigned to your $file variable** and thereby ends up the target "filename" of the new tar file you're trying to create.  That's probably not what you actually want -- I expect that you're trying to create the new tarballs as e.g. "../Place2_1.0.1_1012031412/Project1.tar.gz".  Assuming so, use `basename` to strip off the directories from the pathname.  Something like this:

```
for file in $(
    find /data/shares/builds/place1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name '.*'
  ); do tar zcf  ../Place2_$1_$timeStamp/$(basename $file).tar.gz $file;done
```

Finally, note that you will need to have created your Place2_$1_$timestamp directory manually, in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough response. I am new to unix, so I am very grateful for the awesome explanation. Sorry about the delay in accepting your answer.